# Wix Bootstrapper - Installer runs but does not start installation. No Errors

Tags: sql-server, wix, bootstrapper

I followed the [Wix Extented BootStrapper Application](http://wixextba.codeplex.com/) and am creating an Integrated installer which when called would install SQL Server first and then install my MSI Package which needs SQL Server installed.

The installer presents the custom themed bundle screen. Based on conditions of installs, it also proceeds to next screen and starts installing SQL Server (atleast shows the progress window). However it does not actually install the SQL Server. Neither does it show any error for the same.

Below is the CHAIN tag for my Bundle

```
<Chain DisableSystemRestore="yes">
      <ExePackage          
          Id="SQLSERVER"
          SourceFile ="$(var.SqlDownloadUrl)"         
          Name="SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe"         
          Compressed="no"         
          DetectCondition="SqlInstanceFound"         
          InstallCommand="$(var.SqlInstallCommand)"         
          UninstallCommand="$(var.SqlUninstallCommand)"         
          RepairCommand="$(var.SqlRepairCommand)"
          LogPathVariable="MyLogDestination"
          InstallCondition="RadioButton1 = 1">
      </ExePackage>
      <MsiPackage Id="MYINSTALLER_SERVER"
                  SourceFile ="$(var.myInstallerLocation)"
                  Name="MY Server Installation"
                  DisplayInternalUI="yes"
                  InstallCondition="RadioButton1 = 1"
                  Vital="yes">
        <MsiProperty Name="APPLICATIONFOLDER" Value="[InstallFolder]" />
        <MsiProperty Name="InstallType" Value="Server" />
      </MsiPackage>     
      <MsiPackage Id="MYINSTALLER_CLIENT"
                  SourceFile ="$(var.myInstallerLocation)"
                  Name="MY Client Installation"
                  DisplayInternalUI="yes"
                  InstallCondition="RadioButton2 = 1"
                  Vital="yes">
        <MsiProperty Name="APPLICATIONFOLDER" Value="[InstallFolder]" />
        <MsiProperty Name="InstallType" Value="Client" />
      </MsiPackage>
    </Chain>
```

I even tried to put `DisplayInternalUI="yes"` so that I could see what all was going wrong/failing however that does not show up either.

I only get progress showing that SQL Server is being installed and then my software being installed. After that it lands on "Installer Completed Successfully".

I also do not get to check the logs as none are being created for both the installations.

I feel I am missing something very small yet important here however unable to track that.

Any help.

TIA
Ashutosh

PS - The variables are defined as below

```
<?define SqlServerInstance=MYINSTANCE ?>
  <?define SqlDownloadUrl=Resources\SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe ?>
  <?define SqlInstallCommand=/ACTION=Install/ IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /FEATURES=SQLEngine /INSTANCENAME=$(var.SqlServerInstance) /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS=BUILTIN\Administrators /SECURITYMODE=SQL /SAPWD=P4ND4123 ?>
  <?define SqlUninstallCommand=/ACTION=Uninstall /Q /FEATURES=SQLEngine /INSTANCENAME=$(var.SqlServerInstance) ?>
  <?define SqlRepairCommand=/ACTION=Repair /Q /FEATURES=SQLEngine / INSTANCENAME=$(var.SqlServerInstance) /FEATURES=SQLENGINE ?>
  <?define myInstallerLocation=Resources\MYInstallerNew.msi ?>
```

Comment: It always creates a log in %TEMP%.  There's no way to know what's going on without seeing that log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok

Got it to work.

I assume Wix 3.10.3 is still not supported and because of which it was not working as intended.

I downgraded myself to 3.9 and now it looks to be working perfectly fine.

Thanks
Ashutosh